# How do I determine which connections form cycles in a directed graph's adjacency matrix?

Tags: graph-theory, connectedness, trees, adjacency-matrix, circulant-matrices

given a matrix **A** I know I can perform `A^n = path length from j to v for some entry [j,v]` to find paths to **v**. As I perform this iteration for `n = largest path in A` times I find entries along the main diagonal which shows a path from a vertex to itself-- a cycle. I now need to attribute one or more of the connections to connections which form the cycle(s) for that vertex **v** such that when I remove those connections for all such vertices my graph is acyclic. The operation must be deterministic for a given graph **A**.

I want to remove no more than one connection per cycle. I choose one vertex in every cycle to break the cycle. (I do this deterministically by finding the closest vertex to some designated set of root vertices in the graph)

Currently I can see that if I iterate through removing connections from **v** I can rerun the cycle detection algorithm `A^n from n = 1` and see if the cycle was broken but this becomes a factorial search when considering **v** is a member of multiple, independent cycles.

I suspect that if some vertex **j** is also part of a cycle, the connection **[j,v]** can be said to be the connection which makes a cycle with **v** but I worry this is true for some but not all **[j,v]**.

Answer (score 1):

Small Hint:
If $[A^n]_{i,j} = [A]_{j,i} = 1$ for some $n$, then the connection $j,i$ is in a cicle.

Comment: Thank you I'll try to use this to find the cycle connections for my vertices! So obvious but I was lost in the complexity of things.